# 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' al momento de terminar la acción de savefiledialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms

```
if (guardarImagen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            InsertarEvidencias();
            int cantEvi = 6;
            string nombreEvi = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(guardarImagen.FileName);
            string directorioEvi = Path.GetDirectoryName(guardarImagen.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(guardarImagen.FileName);
            for (var i = 1; i < cantEvi; i++)
            {
                PictureBox evidencia = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("pbVistaPrevia" + i.ToString(), true).First();
                evidencia.Image.Save(directorioEvi + "\\"+ nombreEvi + i.ToString()+ extension);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se especifico ninguna ruta");
        }
```

---

### Título

Al momento de realizar el guardado de varias imagenes utilizando SaveFileDialog, me sale el error de System.NullReferenceException, aún estoy aprendiendo a programar por eso no entiendo la razón del problema.
evidencia.Image retorna un valor null.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Fijate la pregunta relacionada.. debuguea y fijate porque uno de los objetos es null...